# WSUSのクライアントの設定について

Tags: windows-10, windows-server

【マシンA】（WSUSサーバー）
windows server2016（ドメインコントローラー）
ドメイン：samba.ubis.local
アドレス：192.168.1.15
【マシンB】（クライアント）
windows10
ドメイン：PC08.ubis.local
アドレス：192.168.1.20

マシンAにWSUSを構築してから、マシンBを同じドメインに参加させ、マシンBのグループポリシー「イントラネットのMicrosoft更新サービスの場所を指定する」を有効にして、WSUSのアドレスを「http://samba.ubis.local:8530」と入力し、「自動更新を構成する」も有効にして、「gpupdate /force」でグループポリシーを更新しました。それなのに管理ツールを見るとマシンBが追加されていません。
マシンAとマシンBはお互いにpingが飛び、nslookupで名前解決も出来ます。
どうすればマシンBが追加されるようになりますか？教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

> どうすればマシンBが追加されるようになりますか？教えてください。

ipv6を止めたら解決しました。